# "Identifier is undefined" error in accessing "protected" data in sub class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, abstract, protected

Please have a look at the following code

**GameObject.h**

```
#pragma once
class GameObject
{
protected:
    int id;

public:
    int instances;

    GameObject(void);
    ~GameObject(void);

    virtual void display();
};
```

**GameObject.cpp**

```
#include "GameObject.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

static int value=0;
GameObject::GameObject(void)
{
    value++;
    id = value;
}


GameObject::~GameObject(void)
{
}

void GameObject::display()
{
    cout << "Game Object: " << id << endl;
}
```

**Round.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "GameObject.h"
class Round :
    public GameObject
{
public:
    Round(void);
    ~Round(void);


};
```

**Round.cpp**

```
#include "Round.h"
#include "GameObject.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


Round::Round(void)
{
}


Round::~Round(void)
{
}

void display()
{
    cout << "Round Id: " << id;
}
```

I am getting  `'id' : undeclared identifier` error in `Round` class. Why is this? Please help!

Comment: `display` isn't declared as a method inside the `Round` class, so it can't access `id`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this function:

```
void display()
{
    cout << "Round Id: " << id;
}
```

You are trying to access a variable named `id` inside a **non-member** function. The compiler cannot resolve that name, because `id` is not the name of any global nor local variable, therefore you get an error complaining that the identifier was not declared.

If you meant to make `display()` a member function of `Round()`, you should have declared it as such:

```
class Round : public GameObject
{
public:
    Round(void);
    ~Round(void);
    void display(); // <==
};
```

And defined it this way:

```
void Round::display()
//   ^^^^^^^
{
    ...
}
```

This way, function `Round::display()` would override the virtual function `GameObject::display()`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. so in order to override the display() in gameobject I need to re-define it int Round.h?

Comment: @Yohan: First you need to declare it in the definition of the `Round` class, and then you need to provide a definition for it. As in my answer. You can also inline the definition directly inside the class definition: `class Round { public: /* ... */ void display() { cout << "Round id: " << id; } };`

Answer (score 1):

You declared a globally scoped method named `display` in your Round.cpp file.  Edit your header and cpp like this:

Round.h

```
#pragma once
#include "GameObject.h"
class Round :
    public GameObject
{
public:
    Round(void);
    virtual ~Round(void);
    virtual void display(void);

};
```

Round.cpp

```
#include "Round.h"
#include "GameObject.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


Round::Round(void)
{
}


Round::~Round(void)
{
}

void Round::display()
{
    cout << "Round Id: " << id;
}
```

Note - you should make the destructor in GameObject [virtual](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/123-virtual-destructors-virtual-assignment-and-overriding-virtualization/)